# ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE not updating only insert

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to check if a session exists for a customer so that I can either update the session with new session details or insert a session for a customer. I am using the statement below:

```
INSERT INTO sessions (customerid, productlist, date) 
VALUES('33', '{"68":1,"72":1}', '2016-03-03 13:54:56') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE customerid=VALUES(customerid)
```

When I run this, the statement inserts a session for customer even if a session already exists.

Comment: Why not just make a primary key/unique key? then it will error on insersion of it if its duplicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) requires an [`UNIQUE INDEX`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html) on the table. It allows updating the already existing row when the `INSERT` will fail because of the `UNIQUE INDEX`.

The candidate for `UNIQUE INDEX` in your `sessions` table is `customerid`. Do you have such an index?

Anyway, the query you posted doesn't make any sense. `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` kicks in when you want to insert a new row and the value you want to put in `customerid` already exists in the table. The `UNIQUE INDEX` prevents the insertion and `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` allows the updating of some of the other columns of the existing row.

When `customerid` is the `UNIQUE INDEX`, `customerid=VALUES(customerid)` is a [no-op](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOP).

What you probably want is:

```
INSERT INTO sessions (customerid, productlist, date)
VALUES('33', '{"68":1,"72":1}', '2016-03-03 13:54:56')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE productlist=VALUES(productlist), date=VALUES(date)
```

The `SQL` statement to make `customerid` an `UNIQUE INDEX` of table `sessions` is:

```
ALTER TABLE `sessions`
ADD UNIQUE INDEX `customerid` (`customerid`)
```

Or, even better, make is the `PRIMARY KEY` of the table (if the table doesn't already have one:

```
ALTER TABLE `sessions`
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`customerid`)
```

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you create an `UNIQUE key` by using: `customerid` and `pdoructlist` columns.

Comment: Why adding `productlist` to the index?

Comment: Because I am guessing that pdoructlist isn't unique enough, also you can could have duplicated session shared for multiple clients with that solution, so the question is: why would you want to limit yourself?

Comment: It doesn't make any sense. The customer comes on the site (they probably authenticate themselves since they have a `customerid`) and adds products to the cart. The list of products is the data stored in `sessions`, the `date` column contains the last update of the session/cart. It is probably used to remove old entries after some time. Each customer has a single session and a single cart.

Comment: It's purely  for more features and less restrictions. I hate limits but hey, it looks like you are working (or used to work) in some tight corpo software and that's fine from your point of view.
This is only my opinion.